# why does the default _vimrc give E33 No previous substitute regular expression when adding trivial change

Tags: vim

I'm working on Windows with Vim, and copied the example _vimrc to $HOME\Vim\ _vimrc and added one line to the default file to make sure it works

```
set number   (whole vim file below, but it is the developer's example)
```

Trying to save it threw the E33 no previous substitute regular expression error

:version shows this

```
system vimrc file : "$VIM\vimrc
user vimrc file :   "$HOME\_vimrc"
```

I don't think it can be a privileges issue because I am the main user of the home computer.

```
Group Name                                                    Type             SID                                           Attributes                                        
============================================================= ================ ============================================= ==================================================
Everyone                                                      Well-known group S-1-1-0                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Local account and member of Administrators group Well-known group S-1-5-114                                     Group used for deny only                          
Malle-PC\Debugger Users                                       Alias            S-1-5-21-4292279499-377379383-1303777505-1001 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Administrators                                        Alias            S-1-5-32-544                                  Group used for deny only                          
BUILTIN\Users                                                 Alias            S-1-5-32-545                                  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE                                      Well-known group S-1-5-4                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
CONSOLE LOGON                                                 Well-known group S-1-2-1                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users                              Well-known group S-1-5-11                                      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization                                Well-known group S-1-5-15                                      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Local account                                    Well-known group S-1-5-113                                     Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
LOCAL                                                         Well-known group S-1-2-0                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\NTLM Authentication                              Well-known group S-1-5-64-10                                   Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level                        Label            S-1-16-8192                                                                                     


PRIVILEGES INFORMATION
----------------------

Privilege Name                Description                          State   
============================= ==================================== ========
SeShutdownPrivilege           Shut down the system                 Disabled
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege       Bypass traverse checking             Enabled 
SeUndockPrivilege             Remove computer from docking station Disabled
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege Increase a process working set       Disabled
SeTimeZonePrivilege           Change the time zone                 Disabled
```

See line 52 for set number. That's the only thing I added.

```
" An example for a vimrc file.
"
" Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last change:  2016 Jul 28
"
" To use it, copy it to
"     for Unix and OS/2:  ~/.vimrc
"         for Amiga:  s:.vimrc
"  for MS-DOS and Win32:  $VIM\_vimrc
"       for OpenVMS:  sys$login:.vimrc

" When started as "evim", evim.vim will already have done these settings.
if v:progname =~? "evim"
  finish
endif

" Get the defaults that most users want.
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim

if has("vms")
  set nobackup      " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
else
  set backup        " keep a backup file (restore to previous version)
  if has('persistent_undo')
    set undofile    " keep an undo file (undo changes after closing)
  endif
endif

if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  " Switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
  set hlsearch
endif

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

  augroup END

else

  set autoindent        " always set autoindenting on

endif " has("autocmd")

set number 

" Add optional packages.
"
" The matchit plugin makes the % command work better, but it is not backwards
" compatible.
if has('syntax') && has('eval')
  packadd matchit
endif
```

Comment: Well, what is that weird path, `$HOME\Vim_vimrc`? It's supposed to be here: `%USERPROFILE%\_vimrc` or, from Vim's POV, `$HOME/_vimrc`. Also, can we see the **full** content of the file?

Comment: @romainl thank you for responding.In vim, when i do :version, the vimrc is $HOME\_vimrc.  The following is important. I edited the vimrc file in another text editor and now line numbers appear in Vim (so path is not a problem), but when I try to make changes in Vim and save, I get the E33 error that prompted this question, so the question is not solved. Thank you if you can help.

Comment: from the vim tag: For non-programming questions please use https://vi.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Vimscript is programming, @Rob.

Comment: @Leahcim please use markdown properly. If you don't we are going to miss some information. For example, the path in your comment reads as $HOME_vimrc, which is almost certainly not what you meant. So, again, make sure you are using the correct path, both on your machine and in your question/comments.

Answer (score 1):

So…

1. Vim is very Unix-centered so, internally, it tends to use a lot of Unix idioms.

   One of those idioms is the environment variable `$HOME`, which points to the current user's "home" directory. The Windows equivalent of `$HOME` is `%USERPROFILE%`, which, on a regular Windows PC, should point to:

   ```
   C:\Users\username\
   ```
2. The standard location for your `vimrc` is:

   ```
   $HOME/_vimrc
   ```

   which, given the paragraph above, should translate to:

   ```
   C:\Users\username\_vimrc
   ```

   Not `$HOME\Vim_vimrc` or `$HOME\Vim\ _vimrc` or whatever silly path.
3. Don't edit your `vimrc` with anything else than Vim. Other Windows text editors are very likely to add Windows line endings in the file, that will trip Vim up big time.

Now, here is a suggested path for fixing your problem…

1. Delete every Vim-related file from your `$HOME` and undo any Vim-related change you might have made there or elsewhere. This should give you a blank slate.
2. Start a new Vim session.
3. Press `:` to enter command-line mode.
4. Type `edit $HOME\_vimrc` and press `Enter` to execute the command. This should open an empty buffer associated with the given file.
5. Press `i` to enter insert mode.
6. Insert `source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` and press `Esc` to come back to normal mode. This tells Vim to "source" a specific configuration file, with various defaults set to improve the QOL of new users. Forget about that sample `vimrc` you were trying to copy, it doesn't do much beyond that.
7. Press `o` to open an empty line below the current one and switch to insert mode.
8. Insert `set number` to enable line numbers and press `Esc` to come back to normal mode.
9. Do `:w` and press `Enter` to write the file.
10. Do `:q` and press `Enter` to quit Vim.
11. Start a new Vim session, with slightly more comfortable defaults.

From there, I strongly suggest you follow the built-in user manual: `:help user-manual`, which will gradually teach you all you need to use Vim efficiently.

FWIW, I have compiled a number of best practices regarding writing one's own `vimrc` in [this document](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc).

Yes, Vim is weird and using it efficiently requires quite a bit of learning and thus *some* level of effort and discipline. If you can tell right now that you are somewhat not ready to invest the necessary time into it, then you should probably give up and install a more intuitive text editor.

Comment: Regarding 3, it seems Vim can `source vimrc` with DOS line endings. At least that's what's on my Windows machine. Vim is even able to handle a `vimrc` with a BOM. That's what Notepad (not the ++ flavor) sneaks into your files. Bottom line: never ever use Notepad!

Comment: Well that's quite the improvement.